# Merging two csv files and extracting out useful information using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two .csv files that look like following:

file_1:

```
id  a b c
10  1 2 3
11  2 3 4
```

file_2:

```
id   d e 
10   2 3
11   2 3
12   2 3
```

My expected output is:

```
id  a b c d e
10  1 2 3 2 3
11  2 3 4 2 3
```

I wish to merge these two files by comparing the id number. If the id number matched, the id and the corresponding rows need to be merged and extracted. If not matched, the corresponding id number's row is ignored. My code look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
s1=pd.read_csv("file_1.csv")
s2=pd.read_csv("file_2.csv")
if s1['id']==s2['id']:
    merged=s1.merge(s2, on="id", how="outer")
else:
    pass
merged
merged.to_csv("output.csv")
```

After running this coding, I cannot get my expected output. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't have mentioned weather your **id** is index name or a column name, so i took as index.

```
import pandas as pd
s1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[10, 11], 'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,3], 'c':[3,4]})
s2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[10, 11, 12], 'd':[2,2, 2], 'e':[3,3, 3]})
merg = pd.merge(left=s1,right=s2,on='id').set_index('id')
print merg
```

**Here is your Output--**

```
    a  b  c  d  e
id               
10  1  2  3  2  3
11  2  3  4  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.merge`:

```
print(file_1.merge(file_2, on='id'))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  id  d  e
0  1  2  3  10  2  3
1  2  3  4  11  2  3
```

If you care about the order of the columns do:

```
print(file_1.merge(file_2, on='id')[['id', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']])
```

Output:

```
   id  a  b  c  d  e
0  10  1  2  3  2  3
1  11  2  3  4  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not merging the dataframes properly. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
s1=pd.read_csv("file_1.csv")
s2=pd.read_csv("file_2.csv")

merged=s1.merge(s2, on="id")
# Set the index back to id
merged = merged.set_index("id")
merged.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.join` or `pandas.merge` should work here:

```
import pandas as pd
s1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[10, 11], 'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,3], 'c':[3,4]})
s2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[10, 11, 12], 'd':[2,2, 2], 'e':[3,3, 3]})
merged = s1.merge(s2, on='id', how='inner')
# join works as well
# merged = s1.join(s2.set_index('id'), on='id', how='inner')
merged
```

The output:

```
    id  a   b   c   d   e
0   10  1   2   3   2   3
1   11  2   3   4   2   3
```